# Assign new UIViewController or a UIView directly?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

From the standard view-based application, I found that the generated code did this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

So I take it as such that the AppDelegate (self) has a local variable (declared property) named viewController, which is a subclass of UIViewController, and the self.window.rootViewController is pointed towards this view controller.

When a button is clicked on the screen, I would like to jump to a new view.

Now I have created a new subclass of UIViewController, say abcViewController, and a xib file which represents the view. Should I:

(1) replace "viewController" with "abcViewController" so that it becomes the new Application Delegate's window's new rootViewController

or

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:abcViewController];
```

Do I add/remove the view directly, or should I swap the view controllers, then do something to change the view within that view controller? Do I also need a new subclass of UIViewController for every view that I would like to add to the App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this.

In viewController class on which event you want to switch the view at there use this,

-Make object of appDelegate class, 
-then on this object access the window .
-Make object for new view 
-and add it on window.

see this,

```
    YourAppDelegate *obj=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 

abcViewController *objAbc=[[[abcViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"abcViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [obj.window addSubview:objAbc.view];
```

Comment: but then I need to import my AppDelegate.h file in all instances where I need to access the window to add the subview. Is this ideal? On the other hand, I noticed this only add a subview to the window. This does nothing to any view controllers, what should I do with those?

Comment: If you want to make a stack of view then use Navigation controller. Yes you need to import AppDelegate.h file.also for this ideal,this is a way there are some other ways for doing this.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you want it to work visually. Do you want the user to be able to go back to the original view from this new view? Then you should probably use `UINavigationController` as the window's root view controller. Besides the ability to go back to the original view, you will also get a nice animation effect by default -- making it more pleasing for your users than a simple swapping effect.

Almost every control that you see in your app is a subclass of `UIView` -- you don't need to create a view controller for all of them. What you typically do need a view controller for is for the base view of every new "screen". And usually yes, you would subclass `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController` for each of these views.

Comment: The user, on most cases, doesn't need to go back to the previous screen. In this case is it better to replace the view controller and destroy the old one? In the very rare case of needing the old view back, we can always re-create it.